# How to display all class and its base classes members in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper

How to display all class and its base classes members in Visual Studio while in the text editor? What I do is go into any method and type 'this.'. and look at what intellisense displays. Is there an easier way?
I use Resharper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Hierarchies tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Navigation_and_Search__Viewing_Type_Hierarchy.html), which will show the type hierarchy of the currently selected type. You can select each node in the hierarchy and display a preview, which will optionally consist of either the members defined at that point in the hierarchy, or all inherited members.

Comment: 'Show Members' needs to be selected. It's not by default